# Using synthetic filehandle with EV (perl)

Tags: perl, libev, anyevent

I have a filehandle object that is created thus (edited slightly for clarity):

```
sub TIEHANDLE
{
    return $_[0] if ref($_[0]);
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = bless Symbol::gensym(), $class;
    return $self;
}

sub new
{
    my ($class, $fh, $chunk, $interval, $cb) = @_;

    my $self = bless Symbol::gensym(), ref($class) || $class;
    tie *$self, $self;  

    my $data = {
        fh       => $fh,
    };

    ${*$self}{'data'} = $data;

    return $self;
}

sub fileno
{
    my $self = $_[0];
    return ${*$self}{'data'}->{'fh'}->fileno();
}

*FILENO = \&fileno;
```

I want to use this with [`AnyEvent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/AnyEvent). It works fine with [`AnyEvent::Impl::Perl`](https://metacpan.org/pod/AnyEvent%3a%3aImpl%3a%3aPerl) but fails with
[`AnyEvent::Impl::EV`](https://metacpan.org/pod/AnyEvent%3a%3aImpl%3a%3aEV). I think that I have tracked it down to this method from `EV`:

```
static int
s_fileno (SV *fh, int wr)
{
  dTHX;
  SvGETMAGIC (fh);

  if (SvROK (fh))
    {
      fh = SvRV (fh);
      SvGETMAGIC (fh);
    }

  if (SvTYPE (fh) == SVt_PVGV)
    return PerlIO_fileno (wr ? IoOFP (sv_2io (fh)) : IoIFP (sv_2io (fh)));

  if (SvOK (fh) && (SvIV (fh) >= 0) && (SvIV (fh) < 0x7fffffffL))
    return SvIV (fh);

  return -1;
}
```

I think it is failing the `SvTYPE (fh) == SVt_PVGV` test. Using [`Devel::Peek`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel%3a%3aPeek)'s Dump() method I get:

```
SV = PVMG(0x9c98460) at 0x44313b0
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADMY,ROK)
  IV = 0
  NV = 0
  RV = 0x9c21d00
  SV = PVGV(0x9c35510) at 0x9c21d00
    REFCNT = 1
    FLAGS = (OBJECT,RMG,MULTI)
    MAGIC = 0x9a68ee0
      MG_VIRTUAL = &PL_vtbl_backref
      MG_TYPE = PERL_MAGIC_backref(<)
      MG_OBJ = 0x9c217a8
    STASH = 0x4374440   "MetadataStream"
    NAME = "GEN5"
    NAMELEN = 4
    GvSTASH = 0x25d01c8 "Symbol"
    GP = 0x9a43d50
      SV = 0x0
      REFCNT = 1
      IO = 0x9c214a8
      FORM = 0x0  
      AV = 0x0
      HV = 0x9c21ce8
      CV = 0x0
      CVGEN = 0x0
      LINE = 102
      FILE = "/usr/share/perl5/Symbol.pm"
      FLAGS = 0x2
      EGV = 0x9c21d00   "GEN5"
  PV = 0x9c21d00 ""
  CUR = 0
  LEN = 0
```

Any assistance as to how I might adjust the creation of my handle such that it can pass this test would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tied file handles are only partially implemented in perl, and don't work
with EV. Tied handles cannot be made to work with an event library in
general: While some specific cases might work, in most cases where tied
handles are used, they can't work because the readiness notification of an
underlying file descriptor doesn't relate to readiness notifications of
the tied handle.

If your goal is to merely have a thing wrapper around a real file
descriptor, then one way to do it is to copy what IO::Handle and/or
FileHandle do (very ugly, but the only way that works in perl), or use
them as base classes. This doesn't allow you to do interesting things
such as hooking reads and writes, but chances are hooking them makes them
incompatible with event libraries.

Another way is to implement a perlio layer (PerlIO::via). In my
experience, this module is a bit fragile, but gives you all the
options. Again, if you introduce buffering or more interesting things that
decouple the file descriptor from the actual I/O, then it can't be made to
work.

Lastly, if you want to add a new type of handle, then you can create
a new watcher type. This can be as simple as having a function
my_handle_io_watcher that takes your handle, checks for readiness and
creates the kind of low-level watcher that is required.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I guess that about covers it.

Comment: Marc how can I specify the ':via(myfilter)' on an http_get IO handle?

Comment: It seems that using a perlio layer will not work because `AnyEvent::Handle` uses `sysread` which bypasses any such layers.
Similaraly, use of a `IO::Handle`, by using the `tcp_connect` callback to wrap the returned filehandle, fails because `sysread` is used in a non-OO fashion.

Comment: It has nothing to do with OO fashion or not - basically any way to read from the socket that isn't a direct sysread can't work, because these methods do not support I/O readyness notifications.